# IntelliJ automagically mark a target sub directory as "source"

Tags: maven, build, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ since a few months back now for my Java development. I using IntelliJ as IDE and build my projects using Maven. A couple of my Maven projects generates code which my other Maven projects depends upon, the generated code ends up in a target/src-generated directory with "Maven-subdirectories" main/java, main/resource etc. Is it possible to make IntelliJ automagically mark the target/src-generated/main/java directory as source?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the [IntelliJ IDEA Maven FAQ](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Maven_FAQ):

> In order to get generated sources automatically imported as source
>   folders configure corresponding plugins so that they put them into
>   `target/generated-sources/<subdir>`, where subdir is any folder name you
>   prefer. The subdir folder is necessary to distinguish sources from
>   different tools and also to exclude some special generated sources
>   (e.g. groovy stubs).
>
> Please note that even if you manually configure
>   some source folders under `target/generated-sources` of this folder
>   itself, IDEA will rewrite them according to your `pom.xml`.
>
> Any time you
>   want to generate sources you simply execute the corresponding goal,
>   bound for generation (usually `generate-sources`,
>   `generate-test-sources`). After that IDEA will pick up new folders and
>   set them up. Generated test sources/resources should be placed in
>   `target/generated-test-sources/<subdir>`.